# Soft Keyboard hides part of layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, adjustpan

I have a problem where when clicking on the `EditText` at the bottom of my layout, a soft keyboard shows. The issue is that when I click the `EditText` and the soft keyboard shows, I am able to scroll through my ListView, but the layouts I have declared previous to the list view, which are the `ActionBar` and `RelativeLayout`, are both hidden. In my `AndroidManifest` I have declared: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"`. I thought this was because I did not add a `ScrollView` as the parent of my layout but when I did, nothing changed. This was my attempt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/comments_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:id="@+id/comments_appbar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/comments_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/comments_appbar"
        android:id="@+id/view_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="175dp"
        android:background="#e6e6e6">

        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/poster_picture"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            fresco:placeholderImage="@mipmap/blank_prof_pic"
            fresco:roundedCornerRadius="5dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/poster_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:id="@+id/post_date"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/poster_picture"
            android:layout_below="@id/poster_name"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/view_status" />

    </RelativeLayout>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lv_comments_feed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/send_message"
                android:layout_below="@+id/view_post">
            </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/send_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Comment back!"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="send"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

The `RelativeLayout` in the beginning, along with the `ActionBar` are both hidden, but I can still scroll through my `ListView` no problem when my soft keyboard pops up and I click on my `EditText`. Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

**android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"**

Write down

**android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"**

It will help

Comment: This doesn't help because my `EditText` disappears and the area I am typing on seems to be is hidden by the keyboard (it overlaps the `EditText`). Also if anything I would want to simply push up the layouts when clicking the `EditText` because it would  help me be able to see the keyboard, the `EditText`, and if I scroll up or down I can see the layouts.

Comment: According documentation https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#wsoft

`Setting multiple values in either group — multiple "state..." values, for example — has undefined results`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using

```
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

in scrollview and in Manifest file added

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following code in my `AndroidManifest` file :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```